# Statistics Probability of registered American voters sung only in English

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A recent Fox News/Dynamic Opinion Poll reported that 58 % of registered American voters believe that the U.S. National Anthem should only be sung in English. Two registered American voters are randomly chosen. What is the probability that

(a) both feel the anthem should be sung in only in English?

(b) both do not hold the view the anthem should be sung only in English ?

(c) One more registered American voter is randomly chosen. How likely is it that none of the three American registered voters will agree that the U.S. National Anthem should only be sung in English?

---

a) mean = np

0.58 * 2 = 1.16 probability that it should be sung in English

---

b) To find that the anthem should not be in English I used Poisson
x = 2 since 2 Americans

P(X = x) = e^−λ * (λ)^x / x!

```
     = e^−1.16 * (1.16)^2 / 2!
```

to get 0.2109

---

c) I used poisson again

x = 3 Americans

e^−1.16 * (1.16)^3 / 3!

to get 0.0815

What are the accurate solutions and answers? I feel so wrong here

Comment: a) is wrong probabilities can never exceed 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the simple probability multiplication rule.

a) $.58\times.58=.3364$

b) $.42\times.42=.1764$

c) $.42\times.42\times.42=.074088$

Note: Usually you would have to subtract one from the remaining and the total, but there are so many registered American voters that that amount in this problem would be negligible.

Comment: Thank you, have a good night! I'm going to try to remember in 10 mins to accept your answer, can't accept it yet